# how to generate 64 or 128 qam in matlab

Tags: matlab

How to generate 64 or 128 QAM signal in MATLAB without making use of signal processing/Communication tool box. Is there any general method for creating higher order qams?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to generate a QAM for `M=2^b`. Then you need constellation points that form a lattice of `M_I = 2^b_I` by `M_Q = 2^b_Q` points where `M = M_I*M_Q` and therefore `b_I+b_Q==b`. Distributing evenly, we get `b_I = floor(b/2);` and `b_Q = ceil(b/2);`.

This established, you set up the lattice by forming 1-D grids for real and imaginary part and then connect them to a 2-D lattice. Like this:

```
b = 6;
M = 2^b; % b = 6: 64-QAM, b = 7: 128-QAM, etc.
b_I = floor(b/2);
M_I = 2^b_I;
b_Q = ceil(b/2);
M_Q = 2^b_Q;
x_I = -(M_I-1)/2:(M_I-1)/2;
x_Q = -(M_Q-1)/2:(M_Q-1)/2;
x_IQ = repmat(x_I,[M_Q,1]) + 1i*repmat(x_Q.',[1,M_I]);
x_IQ = x_IQ / sqrt((M_I^2+M_Q^2-2)/12);
```

Note that in R2016b, the second-to last line can be simplified to `x_IQ = x_I + 1i*x_Q.';` Moreover, the last line ensures that your constellation to has average energy per symbol of 1 (note: for even `b`, the normalization can be simplified to `sqrt((M-1)/6)`).

Now, `x_IQ` is an array that contains all possible constellation points. 
To draw random symbols, use `s = x_IQ(randi(M,NSymbols,1));`

Note that for odd `b` this script generates a rectangular QAM (e.g., for 128-QAM it is a 16x8 constellation). There are other ways to do so by placing constellation points more symmetrical. There is no unique way of doing that though so if you need one you have to specify which. Though in practice one usually uses QAM with even `b`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! If it is 64,256 or square of any number, then it can be easily generated as below.

```
% matlab code to generate 64 qam 
m = 0;  n = 0;
for k = -7:2:7
    m = m+1;
    for l = -7:2:7
        n = n+1;
     x(m,n) =  k+j*l;
   end 
   n = 0;
end
```

Comment: Okay, it seems that you didn't like my solution. Maybe it looked too complicated. Of course it is good that you found the answer yourself, that is the best way to learn! Just a note: In essence my solution does the same as yours but it can handle any power of 2 and since it has no loops it is a bit faster. Though speed may not be a big concern admittedly. Please note that your constellation is not normalized to unit energy, you may want to do that (I've shown how in my answer).